# Node Js express async response with request and Redis call

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, redis, node-async

So i'm having an issue with handling async actions in NodeJS while trying to send response to a request, with some async calls in the middle. (And to make this party even more complicated, i'm also want to use async.parallel )

Basically i'm trying to get value from Redis, and if he doesn't exist, get it from a provider (with request and response based using axios).

This is the code snippet :

```
this.getFixturesByTimeFrame = function (timeFrame, res) {
    function getGamesData(timeFrame,finalCallback) {
        var calls = [];
        var readyList = [];

        //Creating calls for parallel
        timeFrame.forEach(function(startDay){
            calls.push(function(callback) {
                //Problematic async call
                redisClient.get(startDay, function (error, exist) {
                    console.log('Got into the redis get!');

                    if (error){
                        console.log('Redis error : '+error);
                    }

                    if (exist) {
                        console.log('Date is in the cache! return it');
                        return exist;
                    } else {
                        //We need to fetch the data from the provider
                        console.log('Date is not in the cache, get it from the provider');
                        getFixturesDataFromProvider(startDay)
                            .then(organizeByLeagues)
                            .then(function (gamesForADay) {
                                redisClient.setex(startDay, 600, gamesForADay);
                                responsesList.add(gamesForADay);
                                callback(null, gamesForADay);
                            }).catch(function (response) {
                            if (response.status == 404) {
                                callback('Cant get games from provider');
                            }
                        });
                    }


                });
                }
            )});

        async.parallel(calls, function(err, responsesList) {
            /* this code will run after all calls finished the job or
             when any of the calls passes an error */
            if (err){
                res.send(501);
            } else {
                console.log('Here is the final call, return the list here');
                //Some data manipulation here - just some list ordering and for each loops
                console.log('finished listing, send the list');
                finalCallback(responsesList);
            }
        });


    }

    getGamesData(timeFrame, function (readyList) {
        res.send(readyList);
    });
};

function getFixturesDataFromProvider(date) {
    var requestUrl = 'someURL/ + date;
    return axios.get(requestUrl, config);
}

function organizeByLeagues(matchDay) {
    if (matchDay.count == 0) {
        console.log('No games in this day from the provider');
        return [];
    } else {
        var organizedSet = [];
       //Some list manipulations using for each 
        return organizedSet;
    }
}
```

But the response is been sent before parallel has been starting doing his things...

i'm missing something with the callbacks and the async calls for sure but i'm not sure where...

Thanks

Comment: is the response you're getting a 501? if so, try to add callback("error description") in all of your error cases inside of the async.parallel functions. It will be very hard to spot if you can't tell where is it failing.

Comment: No sorry the response is 500, from the console log debug I can see that the 500 has been sent without even starting the parallel, I mean that no logs from the parallel at all.

Comment: can you add the route that calls getFixturesByTimeFrame? the problem may be outside of your method